# PHP String Compare not working as expected

Tags: php, strcmp

I have an array and some of the values have the text value "unknown".

If I use strcmp, I'm not getting the results as expected.

For example:

```
echo $array[8];
```

outputs the word "unknown".

```
strcmp($array[8],"unknown");
```

outputs -104.

```
strcmp(trim($array[8]),"unknown");
```

Outputs -57.

I don't understand why these strings are not equal. I'm just trying to get a 0 value so I can filter out the array values with "unknown" with a loop.

Comment: You code possibly is not valid. What is `array`? Shouldn't it be `$array` at least?

Comment: Use `var_dump` for a debug output of your array value – that’ll make it easier to see if there is any whitespace contained at the beginning or end of it.

Comment: Edited. I actually have the "$" signs correctly in my code.

Comment: Can you show how you are assigning the word unknown to your `$array` ?

Comment: I got it from doing some preg_spits on some html files. I ended up figuring out it had a left over <td> tag attached to it but I couldn't see it when it wasn't echoed. I should have just var_dumped it from the beginning to check.. :/ Still kind of learning the ropes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to check if string is equal, use `===`

```
if(trim($array[8]) === "unknown"){ ..
```

You can even write your own callback for the filter method:

```
$array_filtered = array_filter($array, function($value){
    return trim($value) !== "unknown";
});
```

Comment: I can never get them to be equal. Even if I copy and paste the exact text from the array and put it in quotes It never registers as being equal.

Comment: @Cake `var_dump($variable)` to check what it really is. Maybe there are some "invisible" characters at the end or beginning.

Comment: I did that and it does have an extra space at the beginning. Why doesn't trim take away that extra space?

Comment: Alight. I did a var_dump and there was some hidden html being included with it... Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You re wrongly trimming it up..

The right way...

```
<?php
$arr[8]='unknown';
echo strcmp(trim($arr[8]),"unknown"); //"prints" 0
```

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](https://eval.in/121543)

Comment: Ya, this works. My string included some leftovers from an html tag that I didn't notice.

Comment: Yeah, it would be clearer if you had posted the array on your question

Comment: Ya, my bad. Still learning how all this works. Thanks for the help though.